# Using promises with Switch statements and embedded functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, post

I am new to creating promises, having to learn it as I need a function to run after multiple other functions have been completed. My issue is how to structure the promises to run so that they are all complete before the final output. My codes is as follows:

```
function callPHP(items) {
    console.log(items);
    console.log(items[0]);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var data = items;
    var postUrl = *link to PHP file*;
    xhr.open('POST', postUrl, true);
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
        items:data
    }));
    
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
            console.log("Got response 200!");
        }
    };              
}

function getUserInfo(aCallback){
    let items = [];
    
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        chrome.storage.managed.get(['primary_domain', 'fields', 'remote_url'], function(values) {
            var primary_domain = values.primary_domain;
            var fields = values.fields;
            if (typeof values.fields == 'undefined') {
                fields = 'annotatedAssetId,annotatedLocation,serialNumber';
            }
            fields = fields.split(',');
            var remote_data = [];
            fields.forEach(function(item) {
                switch (item) {
                    case 'serialNumber':
                        chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes.getDeviceSerialNumber(function(sn) {
                            serial_num = sn;    
                            addToTable({'Serial Number': sn});
                            items.push({
                                Serial:sn
                            });
                    });
                    break;
                    case 'annotatedAssetId':
                        chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes.getDeviceAssetId(function(aid) {
                            asset_id = aid; 
                            addToTable({'Asset ID': aid});
                            items.push({
                                Asset:aid
                            });
                    });
                    break;
                    default:
                        remote_data.push(item);
                    }
            });
        });
        resolve(items);
    }).then(function(result){
        chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo({'accountStatus': 'ANY'}, function(info) {
                email = info.email;
                addToTable({'User': email});
                items.push({
                    User:info.email
                });
                return items;
        });
        return items;
    }).then(function(result){
        aCallback(items);   
    });
    
    
}



document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
        getUserInfo(callPHP);
    }
    
        
};
```

I need the function callPHP() to run after the Serial, Asset and User have been added to the items array. I cannot work out a way to create the promises when Switch statement are being used I am also struggling to see how I can chain the promises together within the multiple embedded functions. Currently, when I post the data to a PHP file, I am getting an empty array. I am quite new to these concepts so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you everyone! :-)

Comment: getDeviceSerialNumber, getDeviceAssetId and getProfileUserInfo this are promises, aren't they ?

Comment: @RohanVeer They are functions I believe. At the moment I only have one promise, chained using .then, which is not working.